# Why is ImageStatistics.Gray null?

Tags: c#, null, histogram, aforge

I'm using AForge.net and I want to show in a textbox the value of the standard deviation. The following code is not working:

```
AForge.Imaging.ImageStatistics stat = new AForge.Imaging.ImageStatistics(btm_1);
AForge.Math.Histogram gray = stat.Gray;
this.textB_1.Text = gray.StdDev.ToString();
```

It fails with the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Both `gray` and `stat.Gray` are null.

Comment: It's not standard *divide*. It's standard *deviation*.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a grayscale image?

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/937b609f-8d95-662f-c4ac-55eebc44a1cf.htm) for the `Gray` property says:

> Note:The property is valid only for grayscale images (see [IsGrayscale](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f687fef4-e354-d165-77d1-bd12ed1bbe5a.htm) property).

I'm guessing that your image is not a grayscale image, and the `Gray` property is returning null. It would be preferable that it throw an `InvalidOperationException` because it could give some insight into the cause of the error, and it would fail fast.

Comment: For sure I have grayscale image. I binarize it with threshold and I also use Aforge's Canny Edge Detector. It works fine that is why I am suprised I have problem with histogram.